Workflow conflict while merging branch
My repositories are hosted privately in github.com. I am planning to set up GitHub Actions workflows to CI/CD the project. The workflow is like:

There will be a main branch
Developers will make a feature branch from the main branch
The develop their feature and push to the feature branch
Once it is tested and approved to go live, they raise a pull request to merge their code to the main branch

I have successfully set the workflow YAML file and pushed to main branch - .github/workflows/main.yml. The issue I am about to address is with the merge conflict that I get when raising a pull request from the feature branch to the main branch.
name: Deployment Pipeline
env:
  BRANCH: branch_name
  DEPLOY_REPO: https://${{ secrets.GH_PAT }}@github.com/xxx/yyy
  PACKAGE: ghcr.io/xxx/yyy/zzz
  DEPLOY_PATH: /tmp/deploy
  KUBECONFIG: ${{secrets.KUBECONFIG}}
on:
   push:
    branches: [ branch_name ]
jobs:

This is the workflow file I am using. The PACKAGE and DEPLOY_REPO value is specific to each branch and because of that I need to hard-code the values in the YAML file.
When developers raise pull request from their feature branch, we are facing merge conflict because of this particular file.
If I am making PACKAGE and DEPLOY_REPO as a variable, I will be ending up with so many variables and I don't prefer that way. How is this actually handled and what is a recommended way to set up workflow actions in such a workflow.

You could generate those PACKAGE and DEPLOY_REPO variables automatically based on the feature branch name during the workflow execution, in a "setup" job, that would then export those variables as outputs for the next operations.

@GuiFalourd, thanks for your reply. I have around 150 git hub repositories and more than 100 branches in each repos. Adding these as a variable would make the process complicated and will end up with so may variables. I am looking for a recommended best practice to tackle such things. Please help.

If you do this process in a reusable workflow to centralized it, you will just have to share it with your 150 repositories afterwards for all of them to follow the same pattern. Then, you will be able to do what I suggest above in the first job of this reusable workflow.
